# Find the item in a list with the maximum number of factors that appear in that same list and output maximum (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, performance

I am trying to write a function that takes in a list of integers and finds the maximum number of factors that appear in that same list. For example, if I have a list with contents 9,5,6,3,2 then 9 has two factors that appear in the list (9 & 3), 5 has one factor that appears in the list (5), 6 has three factors that appear in the list (6, 3, 2), and so on. In this case, the output would be 3 (6 has the max number of factors that appear in the list with 3 total). This is what I have so far:

```
def divisibility(keys):
    #sort keys in descending order - larger numbers w same divisors
    #will always have more factors so we can remove them from the list if they are used
    sortkeys = sorted(keys,reverse=True)
    #compare max divisibility to divisibility of each number in keys 
    #(will always be at least 1 since a number is always divisible by itself)
    max_divisibility = 1
    while len(sortkeys) > 0:
        divisibility = 1
        #when done testing largest number, remove it from the list
        removekeys = [sortkeys[0]]
        for i in range(1,len(sortkeys)):
            #test largest number
            if sortkeys[0] % sortkeys[i] == 0:
                divisibility += 1
                #remove that number from the list
                removekeys.append(sortkeys[i])
        if divisibility > max_divisibility:
             max_divisibility = divisibility
        #remove keys in list
        sortkeys = list(set(sortkeys).difference(removekeys))
    return max_divisibility
```

This works sometimes, but in the case mentioned above it fails, because 3 is removed from the list on the first pass, so by the time we get to 6 there are only two factors of 6 left in the list (6 and 2). I know you could just check every single element of the list, but I'd really like to make this as efficient as possible, so any advice there would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

A simpler algorithm is the following.

```
def factors(n, lst):
    ' Count of factors of n in list lst '
    return sum(n % i == 0 for i in lst)

def divisibility(keys):
    ' Find element in keys with most factors '
    return max(factors(k, keys) for k in keys)

lst = [9,5,6,3,2]
print(divisibility(lst))  # 3
```

Comment: Then again, they said "**I know** you could just check every single element of the list, **but**...".

Comment: @superbrain that wouldn't be the most optimal way to solve it, judging by the time complexity

Comment: @AbhinavMathur Sorry, I don't see what your point is.

Answer (score 2):

You can use sum() in a comprehension to count the factors of each number and then max() to get the highest count:

```
def maxFactors(N): return max(sum(a%b==0 for b in N) for a in N)

maxFactors([9,5,6,3,2]) # 3
```

While it may be possible to reduce the complexity from O(n^2) to O(NlogN) or less, the actual performance may not be better because of the higher overhead required.

for example (using sorting and binary search):

```
from bisect import bisect_right
def maxFactors(N):
    sN     = sorted(N)
    return max(sum(n%sN[i]==0 for i in range(0,bisect_right(sN,n))) for n in N)
```

This is actually slower than the previous one on the small example [9,5,6,3,2] but performs 3% better for a list of 50 values and 45% better on 500 values.

Some optimization could provide better performance when the data meets specific conditions such as when the ratio of maximum/minimum is smaller than the number of elements.

for example:

```
from collections import Counter
def maxFactors(N):
    fRange = range(1,max(N)//min(N)+1)
    cN     = Counter(N)
    return max(sum(cN[n//f] for f in fRange if n%f==0) for n in cN)
```

This would give an O(NxF) complexity where F is the ratio of maximum/minimum.
It is also slower than the first one on the small example but runs 8 times faster on range(25,75) and 38 times faster on range(250,750)

To get the best performance you could select one of these 3 based on a quick assessment of the data.  For example, use the Counter() approach when the max/min ratio is less than len(N) or use the binary search when len(N) is large enough.

```
def maxFactors(N):
    fRange = range(1,max(N)//min(N)+1)
    if len(fRange)<len(N):
        cN = Counter(N)
        return max(sum(cN[n//f] for f in fRange if n%f==0) for n in cN)
    if len(N) < 50:
        return max(sum(a%b==0 for b in N) for a in N)
    sN = sorted(N)
    return max(sum(n%sN[i]==0 for i in range(0,bisect_right(sN,n))) for n in sN)
```

Comment: This is awesome - thanks for this! Really like this approach

Comment: It would definitely reduce your total number of iterations but I don't think it's O(NlogN).
It's still O(N^2).

Answer (score 1):

I like @DarrylG's answer, but still, here's a modified version of the algo in the question, which does print 3:

```
def divisibility2(keys):
    #sort keys in descending order - larger numbers w same divisors
    #will always have more factors so we can remove them from the list if they are used
    sortkeys = sorted(keys)
    #compare max divisibility to divisibility of each number in keys 
    #(will always be at least 1 since a number is always divisible by itself)
    max_divisibility = 1
    while len(sortkeys) > 0:
        divisibility = 1
        #when done testing largest number, remove it from the list
        largest = sortkeys.pop()
        for elem in sortkeys:
            #test largest number
            if largest % elem == 0:
                divisibility += 1
        if divisibility > max_divisibility:
             max_divisibility = divisibility
    return max_divisibility
```